# PyQT5 - How to use QCompleter, QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer, pyqt5

I'm trying to use QCompleter to get something like in the image. The code seems pretty simple, but in my dialog nothing happens.

Is there some problem in this code?

The dialog is created using Qt Designer.

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QCompleter

#

def run(self):
  if self.first_start == True:
    self.first_start = False
    self.dlg = SelectFeatureDialog()

    strList = ['Python', 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'QML']   
    completer = QCompleter(strList)
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)  

  self.dlg.show()
```

---

Are there some errors in these settings?

[image]

---

I'm very stupid, the completer works but I was trying with the lowercase, while in my string's list the first letter is always uppercase.

Now I'm wondering how to ignore the case?

Comment: Does the script have 'dialog event loop' line after  `self.dlg.show()`, like `result = self.dlg.exec_()`?

Comment: yes, sorry I did not write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to OP's edit to the question...

to make the completer case insensitive, use the `setCaseSensitivity()` method:

```
strList = ['Python', 'PyQt5', 'Qt', 'QML']   
completer = QCompleter(strList)
completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
self.dlg.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, did you read my Edit2?

Comment: @Lorenzo, I just edited my answer!

Comment: Hi, you are very kind and I'm very noob. What should I import? It says "Undefined variable 'Qt'. Thank you again

Comment: I solved using completer.setCaseSensitivity(0)

Comment: Great @Lorenzo, otherwise you can just add it to the first line of import statements: `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, `etc

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the reason about the problem, but if you remove 'dialog event loop' line, then, string-completion facilities works.

[image]

```
#

    self.dlg.show()

    # REMOVE FOLLOWING LINES
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I remove that lines then my plugin becomes useless, because the processing is after that.

Comment: @Kadir Şahbaz, I upvoted your answer. I hope you forgive me for  adding my answer with the benefit of the OP's question edits!!